# hiding a element using dojo in zend

Tags: dojo

```
dojo.addOnLoad( function() {
 attach on click to id="textDiv"
 dojo.query('#Specific_consultant-Yes').onclick( function(evt) {
//    document.getElementById("Consultants").style.visibility = "hidden";
        dojo.style.setVisibility('Consultants', false);
//alert('hai');
});
});
```

I tried to write code like this in zend in views page . the alert command works but the hiding of element does not work!!!any problem in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the following code:

```
dojo.style("Consultants", "visibility", false);
```

i suspect the id of the element to be hidden is "Consultants"?

if this is not working, please provide your html-code.

Comment: It did not work  
<div class="field50Pct"><div class="fieldItemLabel"><label for="Consultants" class="required">Consultants</label>

</div><div class="fieldItemValue">
<select name="Consultants" id="Consultants">
    <option value="1" label="Krishna">Krishna</option>
    <option value="2" label="Krishna1">Krishna1</option>
    <option value="3" label="Pradeep">Pradeep</option>
    <option value="4" label="Sudeep">Sudeep</option>
</select></div></div><div class="clear"></div>

Comment: dojo.addOnLoad( function() {
 dojo.query('#Specific_consultant-Yes').onclick( function(evt) {
//    document.getElementById("Consultants").style.visibility = "hidden";
alert('hai');
 dojo.style.setVisibility('Consultants', false);
});
});

is the dojo code